# How to tab to and then "click" a div with the keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, focus

I have replicated a checkbox using html and knockout. It is all working great except that i have just realised that the user will not be able to tab select these checkboxes (focusing them using tab and then selecting them using either space or enter)

Each checkbox is made of a div and i can make this focusable by adding tabindex="0", however pressing space or enter is not triggering my click binding.

Is there a way of easily wiring this up?

```
<div class="checkbox" tabindex="0" 
     data-bind="'css': { 'checked': IsAdmin }, 'click': toggleIsAdmin">
    <div class="Icons_checkboxnotticked-png sprite" 
         data-bind="'css': { 'Icons_checkboxticked-png' : IsAdmin}"></div>
    <label>Is Admin?</label>
</div>
```

Comment: add keypress handler and then trigger click

Comment: hmm, yes, i am looking into the event binding now. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html

Answer (score 0):

Okay i did it like this,

```
<div class="checkbox" tabindex="0" 
     data-bind="'css': { 'checked': IsAdmin }, 
                'click': toggleIsAdmin, 
                'event': {keypress: toggleIsAdmin}">
    <div class="Icons_checkboxnotticked-png sprite" 
         data-bind="'css': { 'Icons_checkboxticked-png' : IsAdmin}"></div>
    <label>Is Admin?</label>
</div>

var vm = function()
{
    ...

    var spaceKey = 32, enterKey = 13;

    var toggleIsAdmin = function (data, event)
    {
        if (!event.keyCode 
               || event.keyCode == spaceKey 
               || event.keyCode == enterKey)
        {
            this.IsAdmin(!this.IsAdmin());
        }
    };

    ...
}
```